# open graph protocols not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have been trying to implement open graph protocols on my pages and keep getting errors through the facebook debugger - at first I was getting

Could Not Follow Redirect Path - Circular redirect path detected

and research suggested this could be fixed by making

```
<meta property = "og:url" content="http://www.mandyevansartist.com/newsletterone/index.html" />
```

into

```
<meta property = "og:url" content="http://www.mandyevansartist.com/newsletterone/index.html/" />
```

(adding the backslash at the end)

but this has created even more errors and dependent on wether I put the backslash on the end of the address when i plug it into the debugger - will not scrape any information at all - at this point i am getting

'URL returned a bad HTTP response code'

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta property = "og:title" content="Noahs Ark|Mandy Evans Artist|Newsletter One" />
<meta property = "og:description" content="Noahs Ark is the limited edition print showcased by unique artist Mandy Evans in this first website newsletter" />
<meta property = "og:image" content="http://www.mandyevansartist.com/newsletterone/images/sendinglove1.jpg" />
<meta property = "og:url" content="http://www.mandyevansartist.com/newsletterone/index.html/" />
<meta property = "og:type" content="website"/>
```

could someone point out what i am missing

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your server is returning with a 301 code. You can see that with the following:

```
curl http://www.mandyevansartist.com/newsletterone/index.html 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>301
Moved Permanently</title> </head>
<body> <h1>Moved Permanently</h1> <p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.mandyevansartist.com/newsetterone/index.html">here</a>.</p> </body></html>
```

Note that you redirect from `...newsletterone...` to `...newsetterone...`. But, the `og:url` provided points to `newsletterone` again, which will cause the crawler to get in a loop.

This is the part that you need to fix.